# Add GestureRecognizer to a SubView

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

I have this code. I'm using the GestureRecognizer to call another method but when testing it on my iPhone the TapGestureRecognizer sends nothing. I thought it was a problem with the handleSettingsDismiss so I changed it to print something to know if it was recognizing the tap. But it did nothing and I get nothing on console. I don't know what is wrong.

```
func showSettingsMenu() {
    if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
        blackView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        blackView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.5)
        blackView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleSettingsDismiss)))
}

@objc func handleSettingsDismiss(){
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5){
        self.blackView.alpha = 0
        if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow{
            self.collectionView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: window.frame.height, width: self.collectionView.frame.width, height: self.collectionView.frame.height)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 'doesn't work' mean the blackView does not set alpha = 0 when you tapped?

Comment: Not only that but it doesn't work at all. Try with printing something but nothing

Comment: What exactly not working which suppose to be? `handleSettingsDismiss` method is not calling? your if condition in `showSettingsMenu` is false?

Comment: We often say here that "does not work" is the least informative fault report possible. Thus, using the phrase at all, especially with no other information, is like painting a target on your back and saying "downvote me". `:=)` Instead, say what you expected to happen, what actually happened, and what you have researched about a possible fix. If there are any logs or errors, show your readers those.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @halfer Thank you very much it is my first post. I've tried fixing it.

Comment: UPDATE: When writing the code in my homeController class the one that called SettingsLauncher class it works fine. I don't know what is the problem when writing the code in SettingsLauncher and calling it from the HomeController class.